# Python: How can I generate a bar graph from 2D array

Tags: python

I have a 2D array (3x3), and I want to generate a bar graph from each row vector that contains 3 bar charts like this: http://www.flickr.com/photos/altaf009_forums/8265573801/

This is easy with MATLAB 'bar' function, just passing the array as a parameter, how can I do it in python? I also want those xticklabels as shown in the picture. Thanks.

Comment: The general answer to this kind of display questions is: use matplotlib (http://matplotlib.org/gallery.html). That said, I don't think there what you want is directly in matplotlib… Matplotlib is powerful enough to do it, though (not exactly sure how).

Comment: First is your array a numpy array? Array is not a standard data type in python.

Comment: http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/ Might help

Answer (score 3):

You can probably adapt (and simplify) the following Matplotlib example from their website: http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/barchart_demo.html.

[image]